# NASM drawing in protected mode

Tags: drawing, nasm, protected-mode

I seen that using interrupts it is only possible to draw on low resolution. Let's say that I am making  simple OS that would display on any resolution, like 4k, 1920x1080. I have Intel x64 processor with Intel HD graphics and Nvidia card. I am on laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IBM PC architecture video memory (framebuffer) is mapped to conventional memory so you can draw by direct writing to video memory. [Here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Drawing_In_Protected_Mode) is a nice doc on that. But beware of screen flickering which happens when you write video memory at the moment of redrawing screen by videoadapter. In order to avoid this you can use double buffering technique which is described here.

Comment: Yes, it will work with any graphic videomode that is supported by your videocard. Usually it is `VGA` mode, some `SVGA` (sometimes also called `VESA`) modes, and legacy old videomodes modes like `CGA` and `EGA`, but I hope you won't use them - they has VERY limited abilities

Comment: So everything is in that link you gave me?